# IE Sessions in Terminal Server

Tags: windows-server-2003, terminal

Currently we are using WADE middleware for our order processing operation. We have about 40 operators that use 1 terminal server to open IE 8 to access the WADE middleware. To me, it's random, but every now and then someone will come to me and tell me that IE has a "Page cannot be displayed" or "HTTP Error 500" error.

I did a bit of testing on my local machine and I never get this error while doing normal operations. Although, when I open one session with username "test" and then login to the wade admin console as admin, I run into problems. I do not run into problems until I logout of the wade admin. Once I logout of the Wade admin, my "test" session says "page cannot be displayed".

This makes me think the IE user sessions on the terminal service are cross talking. Does anyone have any possible settings I can change in IE or do you think this is an issue with the middleware?

The Terminal Server is Windows 2003, btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP Error 500 is a response given by the **server**.  I suspect something is wrong with how it handles sessions.

Comment: I talked with some developers and they said the middleware is not 100% compatible with IE 8 because of the way IE 8 handles sessions. Looks like I'll be rolling back to IE 7 =/. Let the problems begin.

Comment: It pays to trust your error messages and read your logs. ;-)  Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I would suspect the middleware component. I've never heard of processes in two different TS sessions interacting with each other, either at the process level or at the network level.